# How to make the user be able to move the google maps camera only with two fingers?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I want to make my map moving only when user drag it with two fingers, I still want to have ability to zoom and rotate map. Map is in the Stack widget and also is in the SingleChildScrollView (Stack is under ScrollView and GoogleMap is under Stack).
That's my implementation of map:

```
GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
     target: _initialPosition,
     zoom: ShippingAddressUI.initialZoomValue),
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
     _mapController = controller;
  },
  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
)
```

I know about `gestureRecognizers` existing but I have no idea how to use them to do this. I was wondering about `MultiDragGestureRecognizer()` but `gestureRecognizers` take only `OneSequenceGestureRecognizer()` that's why we can't use `MultiDragGestureRecognizer()` here.
If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Did u find solution? I am looking for an answer.

Comment: No, I didn't, I have decided to add a button that enables/disables map. If you find any solution, please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
    target: .....
  ),
......
...
  gestureRecognizers: Set()
    ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code allows you to drag the map horizontally with one finger, and then moving with two fingers vertically makes us move the entire view (via SingleChildScrollView). But I will try to disable this behavior in ScrollView, maybe it will help somehow